# Trouble understanding しちゃア　and ending かい

Tags: meaning, sentence

> そんなに絶望的な顔を**しちゃア**、妾の涎が止まらなくなっちまうじゃあなィか**い**♪

I don't understand what that means. What is しちゃア and the last い ?

I assume it means something like :

> I can't stop drooling if you keep making that desesperate face.

Comment: You should be lookng at 「かい」 and not 「い」.  This 「かい」 has been discussed many times here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, is ちゃ, たら ? "そんなに絶望的な顔をしたら、" ?

Comment: ちゃあ is a contraction from ては (not たら) or といえば.

Comment: What does that mean in the sentence, then ? 顔をしては、？

Comment: @Ushiromiya It means "if you make (such) a face", as you correctly assumed.

Answer (score 3):

> そんなに絶望的｛ぜつぼうてき｝な顔｛かお｝をし**ちゃア**、妾｛わらわ｝の涎｛よだれ｝が止｛と｝まらなくなっ**ちまう**  **じゃあ** 「**なィかい♪**」

It could be said formally like:

> そんなに絶望的｛ぜつぼうてき｝な顔｛かお｝をし**たら**、妾｛わらわ｝の涎｛よだれ｝が止｛と｝まらなくなっ**てしまう**  **では** 「ないかい♪」
>
> そんなに絶望的｛ぜつぼうてき｝な顔｛かお｝をし**たら**、妾｛わらわ｝の涎｛よだれ｝が止｛と｝まらなくなっ**てしまう**。「**そうは思わないかい？**/**そうだよね。**」

*I couldn't stop drooling if you keep making that hopeless/desperate face. Don't you think so?*
*I couldn't stop drooling if you keep making that hopeless/desperate face,right?*

---

> 「わらは」（妾・私）は、武家時代、女が自分をへりくだっていう語（『広辞苑』）

妾｛わらわ｝ or 私｛わらわ｝ is a word that a woman calls herself humbly in the feudal period in Japan.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like manga-style sentence attempting to represent the way people speak. I suspect the しちゃア is a contraction of してしまう, which is often contracted to しちゃう in everyday speech, in a dialect where that last う becomes an ア sound.

The last い simply looks like one of the many occasions where the regular か for questions becomes かい in speech.

Your translation might work if the speaker is the concubine/mistress (妾), but without further context, I'm hard pressed to understand why a concubine (several concubines?) would be drooling over someone looking especially down.

Comment: The questioner said that 妾 is not 妾｛めかけ｝ but 妾｛わらわ｝ that means I/me. I looked it up in a dictionary, and I got that 妾｛わらわ｝ is a word that a woman calls herself humbly in the feudal period in Japan.

Comment: I hadn't caught that clarification when I first replied, and completely overlooked the わらわ reading when I looked up the _kanji_. It certainly makes more sense when read that way!